# Are files accessible when moving their directory to a different one?

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems, locking

I have a folder of videos in a certain location, say C:\Temp.

I move the entire directory along with its contents to a "processing" folder, all the while I have a crawler that reads the moved directories from the "processing" folder and I'm fearing that in an extreme situation, the crawler might attempt to read from a directory that is not yet copied in its entirety.

I've tried testing it myself and it seemed to be okay (it processed the file I moved successfully) but I want to verify this situation before moving to production setting.

TLDR; I have two videos in a folder and I move them to a different location while simultaneously trying to read from that directory with another thread, is it possible that the other thread will be able to access the directory even if the copy is not yet "done"?

Comment: You'll be able to read from that directory, but I suspect that files being copied will not be able to be accessed due to filelock

Comment: I guess if you´re just reading the new location everything should be okay unless the folder itself doesn´t exist. But the files being copied may have a lock on them hindering you from reading them from within the new directory.

Comment: I'll ask a bit of a different question then, is it possible to move a directory while locking the entire directory untill copy is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to access a folder whilst files from that directory are being moved (permissions aside...). If you're crawling through a folder and run into a file that is locked due to being copied/open by another program I use the below as an extension method to manage that.

f = file, c = current attempt, m = max attempts

```
public static bool IsFileLocked(this FileInfo f, int c, int m)
{
    if (c > m) { return true; }
    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        fs = f.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return IsFileLocked(f, c + 1, m);
    }
    finally
    {
        fs?.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

In use

```
var f = new FileInfo(@"C:/Current/Path/To/File.txt");
if (f.IsFileLocked(0, 50)) {
       //The file is locked.                 
}
```